# Proper convention for library calls in functions

Tags: r, function

I have recently taken it upon myself to write an easy to use package which can be used in my work. One of the functions in this package is implemented on a `cronjob`. I find the functions work well, but I receive a lot of internal mail  on the server on `mutt` due to library messages. What is the correct convention to handle these message so that they are suppressed?

Currently a `DB` call function might look as follows:

```
Get_Ids <- function(from = Sys.Date(), to = Sys.Date()){
    if(!require(RMySQL))
    {
    install.packages("RMySQL")
    suppressMessages(library(RMySQL))
    }

    db.con <- tryCatch({dbConnect(MySQL(), host= "localhost", dbname = "ID_db")}, 
                    error = function(e) {1})

    if(class(db.con) == "MySQLConnection")
    {                   
    Query <- paste0("Select * from ID_tbl where Date between '", from,"' AND '", to," 23:59:59';")

    Ids <- tryCatch({dbGetQuery(db.con, Query)}, error = function(e) {1})

    dbDisconnect(db.con)
    return(Ids)
    }else
    {
        return("Error occured")
    }
 }
```

But as soon as I run

```
 Get_Ids()
```

I get the following msg on console

```
Loading required package: RMySQL
```

Comment: Why not just direct output to `/dev/null` in the cronjob?

Comment: `?suppressPackageStartupMessages`

Comment: Thanks @DirtySockSniffer! That is what I am looking for! @nrussel, There is other output in the function that needs to end up on mutt if they are triggered in some odd manner, so `/dev/null` isnt an option

Comment: Furthermore, it is recommended that `require` be used inside functions instead of `library`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. One last question. Why has R kept that very verbose convention for suppressing package startups? I am thinking of the case where I might load a lot of libraries. Doesnt `R` have a built in function which one can add to the start of a function to divert for ALL package messages? I am thinking in the line of a special `sink(temp(), packages_only =T)`

Comment: ITYM `return(Ids)`